# Regex Match.Value returning entire value, not the matched groups

Tags: c#, regex, curly-brackets

I am currently trying to achieve the relatively simple task of capturing values from a string which exist between sets of curly braces using a regular expression. The expression I have written works fine on a number of online tools I have tested it on, however this is not the case in .NET.

```
String str= "{Value1}-{Value2}.{Value3}";
Regex regex = new Regex( @"\{(\w+)\}");

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

I would expect to get 3 matches of "Value1", "Value2", "Value3". However .NET is also returning the brackets, i.e. "{Value1}", "{Value2}", "{Value3}".

Any help on how this can be achieved would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You used capturing groups `(...)`, so what you want is in the `Groups[1]`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{(\w+)\}");

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Another way is to use zero-width assertions:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)(\w+)(?=\})");

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

In this way the Regex will search for `\w+` that is preceded and followed by the `{` and `}`, but these two characters won't be part of the match.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookarounds:

```
Regex regex = new Regex( @"(?<=\{)(\w+)(?=\})");
```

or use matched group #1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element
>   of the GroupCollection object (the element at index 0) returned by the
>   Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular
>   expression pattern. Each subsequent element, from index one upward,
>   represents a captured group, if the regular expression includes
>   capturing groups.

So `match.Groups[0].Value` is `{Value1}` itself and `match.Groups[1].Value` is `Value1`.