# Match returning capture but not pattern

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

There is a question here:

[Regex Match.Value returning entire value, not the matched groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875959/regex-match-value-returning-entire-value-not-the-matched-groups)

But my question is different

I use

```
var match = _regex.Match(inputString);
return match.Value;
```

And I would like to cope without referring to groups by index. Is it possible?

I would like to have a match which does not return 
`#WORD` from string `#WORD "SOMEWORD"`

Pattern: `^#WORD(.+)$`

Input: `#WORD "SOMEWORD"`

returns `#WORD "SOMEWORD"`

I need only `"SOMEWORD"`

Comment: You can turn your capture group into named `(?<word>.+)` and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/906493/4685428) answer. Or just refer your group by index (1 in your case)

Comment: You already captured the part, access it with `match.Groups[1].Value` or - if you need to trim it - `match.Groups[1].Value.Trim()`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
(?<=^#WORD ")\w+(?="$)
```

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/48uto)

Comment: Do you mean `?<=`? `?!` will superficially work but not for the right reasons.

Comment: Not working, one can put any string instead of WORD

Comment: Sorry I made typo. It is now fixed. can you try again?